# What event(s) to choose to delegate a handler from <select> to the selected <option>?

Tags: javascript, handler, html-select, event-bubbling, event-capturing

When another `<option>` is selected in a `<select>` control, it is possible to process this event with a `<select>`-triggered handler in a quite straight way.
However for some reasons it would be much convenient for my project to use a delegated `<option>`-triggered handler instead.
I tried to trigger and delegate a needed handler with using different events. The results were unsatisfactory:

- `onfocus`, `onchange` and `onkeyup` handlers were triggered only on the `<select>` control and were not triggered on a nested `<option>`.
- `onclick` handler worked as needed and was delegated (triggered on the selected `<option>`). However, it obviously makes no sense to use this handler, as another `option` in a `select` control can be chosen by keyboard too, rather than only by mouse.

Am I right? Did I missed any standard DOM event that can be used in the case? Or I have to use only a kind of polyfill, like jQuery's `focusin` and `focusout`?

Comment: Implementation of select boxes is very different among browsers, they often don't even respond to normal DOM events but are part of a 'twilight zone' inside the browser.

Comment: BTW, I use Firefox currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the discussion there are no DOM event(s) that meet the specified requirements.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand perfectly your need but I will try to answer.

As you are talking about jQuery, I have this solution :

```
$("#my-select").change(function() {
    // $(this) refers to the select element
    $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
        // this function is called only once per change
        // $(this) refers to the selected option
    })
});
```

LIVE EXAMPLE :

```js
$("#my-select").change(function() {
  // $(this) refers to the select element
  $("#s_value").text($(this).val());
  $("#s_text").text($(this).find("option:selected").text());
  $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
    // this function is called only once per change
    // $(this) refers to the selected option
    $("#o_value").text($(this).val());
    $("#o_text").text($(this).text());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<br>SELECTED (FROM SELECT) :
<br>Value : <span id="s_value"></span>
<br>Text : <span id="s_text"></span>
<br>
<br>SELECTED (FROM OPTION) :
<br>Value : <span id="o_value"></span>
<br>Text : <span id="o_text"></span>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Nice try, @Apolo, thank you. Unfortunately, I do not want to use jQuery in this case. Let me to explain my question in a different way. We can, of course, assign a handler to a `<select>` control for every event from a series of standard DOM events. I hoped that it is possible to choose an event that will trigger the assigned handler for an `<option>` of this `<select>`, when this option is selected. It seems to me now that it is not possible.

Comment: It is not possible as you say. But you can get the same behavior from the select events. You can translate my answer to pure js. If you can't, I will try on Monday. Put a handler on the "onchange" event of the select elemeny and get the selected option.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can do this myself. My problem is that in my project I need to maintain the history of the handlers applied within a certain page. Initially I created this history as the list of "actions" (aka pairs `[element, handler]`) and did not included in this list any pair that repeated the previous one. But within this approach consecutive selections of different `<option>`s of the same `<select>` looks like the same "actions", so only the first of them goes to the history. It's because now I have to reconsider this algorithm.

Comment: A translated to JS version would be useful to others especially as OP needed a non-jQuery solution.

Comment: Dear @SamuelGfeller, I wrote that answer more than 7 years ago when jQuery was very common. I did not assumed OP was using jQuery, but I tried giving a hint at how it could be solved. TBH I'm not going to update everything I wrote back in the days, I advise you to open a new question to have up to date answers. BTW, the change event as a target property which would be the select element, which has a children property, which are the option elements. So this solution can be translated, although I reckon it require some work. good luck !